# Big problem when exporte normal map from Substance Painter to Blender

Tags: normals, texture-painting, normal-map, opengl, eevee-render-engine

I need help.

I have this problem when I export a normal map from Substance Painter to 
use in Blender.
As you can see in the images it show some dark spots in the object, and 
it looks worse at glancing angles.
I exported the normal map in OpenGL and it is configured in the node as 
"Non-Color Data".
I already tried to invert the normal map channels but the same thing 
keep happening, it is also worse if I export the normal map in 16bits 
instead of 8 bits.

on Cycles the problem does not shows up, but it does show up on 
everything else on Blender, even on Eevee.

Thank you all!

***Edit: As I explained, I've already tried to invert the channels. And yet it does not solve the problem. I've already tried to invert the Y channel, as well as the others.***

**[Blender File 1:](http://lojameca.com.br/subsblen/Bola_Blender.zip)** 
**[Blender File 2:](http://lojameca.com.br/subsblen/Cano45_Blender.zip)** 
**[Substance Painter File 1:](http://lojameca.com.br/subsblen/Bola%20Substance%20Painter.zip)**

[image: wrong normal 1]

[image: wrong normal 2]

[image: nodes setup]

[image: substance export setup]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visible seams on tangent normal maps](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93398/visible-seams-on-tangent-normal-maps) - this is likely due to flipped green channel.

Comment: Hi Sazerac.
As I explained, I've already tried to invert the channels.

And yet it does not solve the problem.
I've already tried to invert the Y channel, as well as the others.

Comment: There must be an issue when exporting from Substance Painter. That would make the question off topic on Blender Stack Exchange since you would have to solve the issue in Substance Painter.

Comment: Hi Martin.
I do not think it's in Substance.
It works normally in cycles and other softwares.

Comment: Silly question, but have you tried flipping the normals on your model? The image looks very like some sort of normal inversion/mismatch to me. Also did you flip the green colour info as describe inhttps://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128103/normal-map-problem-inverting-color/128111#128111 or did you flip the Y in the UV mapping? You need to flip the green channel.

Comment: I had a look at the second file, Normals in blender are fine, green channel is ok, but there is something wrong with the map itself, it seems like there is slightly different curvature  represented in the map. Was the map baked on a lower resolution/subdivision version of the mesh?